# Composite key in gemfire for index

Tags: gemfile, geode

I am using gemfire 8.2 , I have  near about 500 million records in gemfire region and no primary key as data is duplicate and using four column I can get unique combination .

Now issue is that when I am creating index it would be on one column  but since data is duplicate and I want to fire query like

```
select a,b,c,d,e from / myRegion where a=1 and b=2 and c=3 and d=4
```

How can i create index on (a,b,c,d) column ?

Answer (score 0):

In GemFire, the `key` of the `region` is always unique and servers as the primary key. You can try to use the key if you can obtain it at query time or even look into embedding your four fields into `key` so that your query turns into a simple `region.get(key)` operation.

If that is not possible, you can define 4 different indexes on the four fields. Please see [here](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/query_index/create_multiple_indexes.html) on how to do that efficiently.